# images are not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing, image-size

I have two full width images side by side on one of my pages. They work perfectly except for the fact that they do not align on the bottom (you see how the right picture is slightly higher then the left picture). Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

html

```html
<div class="food-featured-posts">

  <div class="food-featured-posts-first">
    <?php query_posts( 'p=185'); while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
      <div class="food-wrapper"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          <div class="popular-sticker">Popular</div></div>
      <div class="food-featured-posts-info">
      <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
      </div></div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>


  <div class="food-featured-posts-second">
    <?php query_posts( 'p=173'); while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
      <div class="food-wrapper"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          <div class="popular-sticker">Popular</div></div>
      <div class="food-featured-posts-info">
      <h2><a class="post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p class="post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
            <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
            <?php comments_popup_link ('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?>
      </div></div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
```

css

```html
.food-featured-posts-first img {
  width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
.food-featured-posts-second img {
  width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
.food-featured-posts-first  {
  width: 50%;
}
.food-featured-posts-second  {
  width: 50%;
}
.food-featured-posts {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    margin-top:125px;
}
```

fiddle with img tags used instead - https://jsfiddle.net/v90pug4o/4/

Comment: your html contains php codes which can't be run in code snippet

Comment: You can also lay them out using `inline-block` next to one another and they'll align at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to set vertical align of the items inside a flex is to use `align-self` as below:

```
align-self: flex-start; /* vertical align = top */
align-self: flex-end;   /* vertical align = bottom */
```

so your problem in fiddle can be fixed easily by adding `align-self: flex-end;` to child divs .food-featured-posts-first and .food-featured-posts-second as this:

```
.food-featured-posts-first  {
  width: 50%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.food-featured-posts-second  {
  width: 50%;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

[image]
i'have tested it and it works properly. [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v90pug4o/5/)

Comment: You can also apply `align-items: flex-end;` to the parent, versus using `align-self` to both children. https://jsfiddle.net/v90pug4o/7/

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes, you are right. But **in general**, using `align-self`we have more control on each item to be aligned vertically top, center or bottom as shown in attached image i have add to my answer

Answer (score 1):

The images are slightly different aspect ratios. If you assign `height: 100%; width: 100%;` to both (only `height: 100%;` is required for both to align at the bottom, but using both height/width so it looks OK sized in the elements in your demo), then they align as expected, though 1) it will change the aspect ratio a little, and 2) if I recall this issue has been posted before, and this doesn't work in Safari. I'm still not sure why. Safari doesn't seem to allow you to force an aspect ratio that's different from the original on an image.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.food-featured-posts-first  {
  width: 50%;
}
.food-featured-posts-second  {
  width: 50%;
}
.food-featured-posts {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    margin-top:125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="food-featured-posts">

  <div class="food-featured-posts-first">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/2855/landscape-mountains-nature-lake.jpg"/ >
  </div>


  <div class="food-featured-posts-second">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/4164/landscape-mountains-nature-mountain.jpeg"/ >
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i think the best way is to use `align-self` as i posted in my ans. it should also work for any content (a `div` containing arbitrary child items) not just a simple `img` tag

Comment: @S.Serp Ah yeah, definitely, I thought OP was trying to make them the same height.